# Failed to iterate over List objects

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

Having trouble with iterator. It need to iterate over ArrayList and find any other Object than this and print it's name. Program uses Threads. How can iterator produce error when it entered `while` loop when `itr.hasNext()` was equal `true`?

Stack trace:

```
Thread [JOE] (Suspended (exception NoSuchElementException)) 
    ArrayList$Itr.next() line: not available [local variables unavailable]  
    Monster.beginFight(Monster) line: 55    
    Monster.run() line: 28
```

Method

```
private void tryName(Monster monster){

    Iterator<Monster> itr = room.monsters.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        if (!itr.next().equals(monster)) {
            System.out.println(monster.getName() + "some text "
                    + itr.next().getName());

            break;
        }

}


}
```

Why do I have in *ArrayList$Itr.next()* tab displaying: *Source not found*?

Comment: Basically, your problem is calling `itr.next()` _twice_ in the loop.

Comment: Remember to compile with debug information to get local variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you call `itr.next` it will advance the iterator to the next element. You need to do something like:

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Monster m = itr.next();
    // rest of your code using m instead of itr.next()
}
```